# Subqueries with update statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, new_time, 101)) As day,
    datepart(hh,new_time) As hour,count(*) As Total
FROM 
   log_table
WHERE 
   new_time > GETDATE() - 180
GROUP BY 
   CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, new_time, 101)),datepart(dd,new_time), datepart(hh,new_time)
ORDER BY 
   CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, new_time, 101)), datepart(hh,new_time));
```

I need to update the table 'tmp_table' based on its results. I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
UPDATE tmp_table
SET count=Total
WHERE date=day AND hour=hour
FROM 
(
    select CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, new_time, 101)) As day,
    datepart(hh,new_time) As hour,count(*) As Total
    from log_table 
    where new_time > GETDATE() - 180
    group by CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, new_time, 101)),datepart(dd,new_time),
    datepart(hh,new_time)
    order by CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, new_time, 101)), datepart(hh,new_time))
)
```

I need to get the values "Total", "day" and "hour" from the subquery.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are different RDBMSs. Which are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to update, then you don't need to order by and therefore you can use a CTE and a join as such:

```
 With CTE AS 
    (
        SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, new_time, 101)) As day,
               DATEPART(hh,new_time) As hour,
               COUNT(*) As Total
        FROM log_table 
        WHERE new_time > GETDATE() - 180
        GROUP BY  CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, new_time, 101)),
                  DATEPART(dd,new_time),
                  DATEPART(hh,new_time)
    )
    UPDATE tmp_table
    SET Count= CTE.Total
    FROM tmp_table INNER JOIN CTE
         ON temp_table.date=cte.day AND temp_table.hour=cte.hour
```